# TextView inside CardView isn't displayed

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a `TextView` inside my `CardView` layout but it's not being displayed on neither the Layout preview nor the live device. Similar questions had answers like "remove tools:android:text=".." " etc. but that's not the issue here. Any ideas?

This is what i'm going for with the cardView:

[image: final image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/explore_desc">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/localEvents"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                    android:text="@string/local_events"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/beach_bg_placeholder" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is the cardView the parent Layout?

Comment: Your text color is white.

Comment: @afhamu no it's a LinearLayout sorry about that

Comment: ok how do you want the TextView and the ImageView to be aligned, an image showing the desired output will be also helpful

Comment: @afhamu just added an image for reference in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code & the following works perfectly. Since the `ImageView` and `TextView` were stacked up inside `LinearLayout`, the text was not showing on top of `ImageView`. Defining the TextView after ImageView puts it 'over' the ImageView like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/localEvents"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/test" />



            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:text="Local Events"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I've tried changing the colors too but that doesn't fix it

Comment: Copy the `TextView` I posted in the answer, add `android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"` and `android:text="@string/local_events"` from your code and it should work.

Comment: I've already done that, it's literally the same `TextView` i posted with a different color but the color isn't the issue here. I've tried multiple colors and different background images but that's not it

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail, please add `android:elevation="@dimen/1dp"` to the `TextView`.

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail I've updated the code with the screenshot & reason why it didn't work because of text & image views being stacked up one upon another.

Comment: You're right, i should have thought of that. Awesome answer, thank you very much. I'll keep it in my mind from now on

Answer (score 0):

**You should be written like below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="TextV'ew"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/america"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```